# Center Arabic symbol letters

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

By default these symbols go above the characters such as `مُحَمَّد`. I wonder if it's possible to center these symbols.

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
}

span {
  font-size: 4rem;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 0.2rem;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="border border-5 border-primary rounded text-white text-center p-2">
  <div class="wrapper mb-4 bg-primary text-white text-center">
    <span class="bg-dark"> َ</span>
    <span class="bg-dark"> ْ</span>
    <span class="bg-dark"> ُ</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
.wrapper,
span {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

But it didn't work.

Also, I tried to separate the symbol inside one more span with `position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);` but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting challenge to figure out. It seems that Arabic characters have 0 width.

Therefore to center them horizontally (using the text-align property) you need to add something to them that adds width. I used the `&nbsp;` character to do this.

[Horizontally with text-align]

```
<span class="bg-dark">
     َ&nbsp;
</span>
<span class="bg-dark">
     ْ&nbsp;
</span>
<span class="bg-dark">
     ُ&nbsp;
</span>
```

Vertically, these characters seem to take up more space than they should (I'm guessing because of their use in the Arabic language). To resolve this I added a another div around the span tags. This also resolves the need to use `&nbsp;`. The background color of this div and the span tags has to be the same (or you can set the `background-color` of the span tags to be transparent). Then you set the height property to the Arabic characters to reduce their height. Then you can use the new div to position the elements vertically and horizontally (through flexbox).

[Horizontally and Vertically with flexbox]

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: pink;
}

span {
  font-size: 4rem;
  height: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border border-5 border-primary rounded text-center p-2">
  <div class="bg-primary text-white d-flex justify-content-center" style="gap: 20px">
    <div class="wrapper bg-dark">
      <span class="bg-dark">
        َ&nbsp;
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper bg-dark">
      <span class="bg-dark">
        ْ&nbsp;
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper bg-dark">
      <span class="bg-dark">
        ُ&nbsp;
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to center them after that?

Comment: Text-align should work. As you can see in the demo, your code is working if you just add &nbsp;. Do you also want to center them vertically?

Comment: Yeah, The main goal is vertically

Comment: Yeah the whitespace charracters are only needed if you want to align horizontally only (with text-align).

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect this. You do need the `&nbsp;` if you want to use text-align to align them just horizontally though.